# Unable to see all element in DOM using f12 as well using XPATH in selenium

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath, selenium-webdriver

My problem is in finding all Dev Data from DOM using XPATH in selenium webdriver so that count number of elements.

Data Resides in Dev tag and have 20 documents. When I do F12 it is showing only 6 items in dev at a time and when I try to find elements using XPATH it is fetching only 6 documents.If I do scroll in UI DOM gets updated and shows new items which are visible in UI now.

So is there any way to get all data (20 Documents) at once from DOM? Scrolling in UI each time and then getting data will be tricky and not feasible.

Below is DOM:

```
<div id="datatable1481094646361" class="webix_view webix_dtable job_table" style="border: 0px solid red; position: relative; width: 1380px; height: 240px;" view_id="optlist-completed">
<div class="webix_ss_header" style="height: 47px;">
<div class="webix_ss_body">
<div class="webix_ss_left" style="width: 0px; height: 193px;">
<div class="webix_ss_center" style="width: 1363px; height: 193px;">
<div class="webix_ss_center_scroll" style="width: 1363px; height: 193px;">
<div class="webix_column webix_first" style="width: 80px; left: 0px; top: 0px;" column="0">
<div class="webix_column " style="width: 322px; left: 80px; top: 0px;" column="1">
<div class="webix_cell">Opt_S_Rel_034</div>
<div class="webix_cell">Opt_S_Rel_033</div>
<div class="webix_cell">Opt_S_Rel_032</div>
<div class="webix_cell">Opt_S_Rel_031</div>
<div class="webix_cell">Opt_S_Rel_030</div>
<div class="webix_cell">Opt_S_Rel_029</div>
</div>
<div class="webix_column " style="width: 321px; left: 402px; top: 0px;" column="2">
<div class="webix_column " style="width: 100px; left: 723px; top: 0px;" column="3">
<div class="webix_column " style="width: 180px; left: 823px; top: 0px;" column="4">
<div class="webix_column " style="width: 180px; left: 1003px; top: 0px;" column="5">
<div class="webix_column webix_last" style="width: 180px; left: 1183px; top: 0px;" column="6">
</div>
</div>
<div class="webix_ss_right" style="width: 0px; height: 193px;">
</div>
```

And In actual similar to Opt_S_Rel_034 there are more than 20 rows available in Application UI.

Using: XPATH= //div[@view_id='optlist-completed']//div[@column=1]
to get all test which is returning only 6 document

Comment: When I scroll dev in UI DOM gets updated with new data. Do we have to fix this from Development side?

Comment: The code snippet that was shared above is not DOM. It is page source.

Answer (score 0):

> If I do scroll in UI DOM gets updated and shows new items which are visible in UI now

The DOM is probably getting updated by JavaScript, which means the documents doesn't exist in the DOM until the update (triggered by the scroll down) and that why you can't see them with F12 and selenium catch only 6. If the documents do not exist in the DOM, Selenium can't fetch them.

Comment: Right. Application is developed in Angular JS so is it possible on that side?

Comment: @RaghuvirSingh The only solution I know of is to scroll down.